# How can I copy a file n Linux terminal, without pasting it?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, 12.04, terminator, cp

I have run this in my Linux machine `# cp file` . Is that command copying file1? Is there anyway to paste file1 in other folder after using above command (whitout `cp file1 path/to/file`)?

Comment: You have tagged 14.04 and 12.04 - which one is it? Please read [ask] and [edit] your question with further details.

Comment: Only supported releases of Ubuntu (*standard support*) are on-topic for this site.  Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is EOL (*end-of-life*) thus off-topic, and Ubuntu 14.04 ESM is in extended support and only supported by Canonical via Ubuntu Advantage thus also off-topic here.  Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades
https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/05/02/ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr-reached-end-of-life-on-april-25-2019-esm-available/    (*same with 12.04 except it reached it's EOL two years earlier*)

Answer (score 3):

> `# cp file` Is that command copying file1?

No. `file` is not the same as `file1`.It will always error out unless you replaced `cp` by a function or an alias.

> Is there anyway to paste file1 in other folder after using above command (without `cp file1 path/to/file`)?

No. `cp` must have a source and a destination.